# Google Map won't load on iPhone simulator

Tags: google-maps, ios-simulator, mapkit

I'm running a test app in the iPhone Simulator to play around with MapKit. I'm using a pretty easy to find program from a tutorial I found via Google. Anyhow, I'm having the same issue as this poster ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667975/google-map-is-not-loading-in-iphone-simulator-can-only-see-the-grid-lines ) such that everything runs but the map is just the default gray grid. I know that the problem is that the simulator isn't connecting to the internet. I'm working at a computer at my university, and so I have to put in my username and password to use the internet (it prompts whenever I open Firefox, Safari, or any other particular program trying to access the internet). I was able to connect to the internet via the simulator's Safari, and it prompted me for a password when it opened.

So, the problem is that the simulator is not prompting me for a password so I can access the internet via my test app. Is there a way to work around this or fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way around this. Do you have a physical device you can test on?

Comment: I don't currently, but I will in the future. I was just hoping to get the simulator working in full before then.

Comment: As you have noticed, the iPhone simulator can be great, but it has it's limitations. To develop an iPhone application you really need a physical device, and if you are looking to achieve a highly diverse user base (iPhones, iPod touches, iPads) you will need numerous devices. I know it sucks, but sometimes there are some things you simply can't do with the limitations of the iPhone. I would suggest you develop any parts of the application you can in the Simulator and then move on to the other pieces once you get your device.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't really something you can get around.

Since you're working with the MapKit, you could always try to set it up via UIWebView (which should allow for username/password) access and then translate that to you app.  Otherwise, this is good practice for detecting an active network connection and display the appropriate content or lack thereof :)

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. I'm a serious novice to all of this, but that advice puts me in the right direction.